# Push forward the date values without overlaps in the given table

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a drug table with date difference calculations.
I want to create a Nw_start and Nw_end date columns for the below given table.

The scenario defines: We have to push forward the overlapping days for each IDs consuming different drugs.

For instance:

ID 123 has started taking a drug from 19Aug to 18Sep so the nw_start & nw_end is remains same for 1st row.

On 2nd row: If the Start_dt > previous End_dt (i.e 1st rows End_dt) - whereas the days not overlapped, so the nw_start & nw_end is remains same for 2nd row too.

On 3rd row: the Start_dt < previous End_dt (i.e 2nd rows End_dt) - The days were overlapped,
so the Nw_start = (prev Nw_End + 1) and Nw_End = (Nw_start + days_supply)

Then the same ID 123 consumes another drug (bbb) so the above statement follows the same logic from the beginning.

| ID | Drug | Start_dt | day_supply | End_dt | dt_diff | Nw_Start | Nw_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aaa | 8/19/2022 | 30 | 9/18/2022 | 5 | 8/19/2022 | 9/18/2022 |
| 123 | aaa | 9/23/2022 | 30 | 10/23/2022 | -3 | 9/23/2022 | 10/23/2022 |
| 123 | aaa | 10/20/2022 | 30 | 11/19/2022 | null | 10/24/2022 | 11/23/2022 |
| 123 | bbb | 8/23/2022 | 90 | 11/21/2022 | -1 | 8/23/2022 | 11/21/2022 |
| 123 | bbb | 11/20/2022 | 90 | 2/18/2023 | null | 11/22/2022 | 2/20/2023 |
| 234 | ttt | 5/10/2022 | 30 | 6/9/2022 | 46 | 5/10/2022 | 6/9/2022 |
| 234 | ttt | 7/25/2022 | 30 | 8/24/2022 | -2 | 7/25/2022 | 8/24/2022 |
| 234 | ttt | 8/22/2022 | 30 | 9/21/2022 | -8 | 8/25/2022 | 9/24/2022 |
| 234 | ttt | 9/13/2022 | 30 | 10/13/2022 | -2 | 9/25/2022 | 10/25/2022 |
| 234 | ttt | 10/11/2022 | 30 | 11/10/2022 | -6 | 10/26/2022 | 11/25/2022 |
| 234 | ttt | 11/4/2022 | 30 | 12/4/2022 | 1 | 11/26/2022 | 12/26/2022 |
| 234 | ttt | 12/5/2022 | 30 | 1/4/2023 | null | 12/27/2022 | 1/26/2023 |

The written query perfectly works for ID 123 but not for ID 234 from 4 row. Need a suggestion to derive the give method.

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT 
      ID,
      Drug,
      Start_dt,
      days_supply,
      End_date,
      DATEDIFF(LEAD(Start_dt) over (partition by ID, Drug order by Start_dt),end_date) as dt_diff,
      CASE
          WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) = 1 THEN end_date
          WHEN LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) < Start_dt THEN end_date
          WHEN LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) >= Start_dt THEN LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) + 1 + days_supply
      END AS Nw_End,
      CASE
          WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) = 1 THEN Start_dt
          WHEN LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) < Start_dt THEN Start_dt
          WHEN LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) >= Start_dt THEN LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Drug ORDER BY Start_dt) + 1
      END AS Nw_Start
FROM harr.PolypharmACH_numer1 order by ID,Drug,Start_dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is processing the data to derive the **Nw_Start** and **Nw_End** columns based on the overlapping days for each ID consuming different drugs.

**The bleow is the code in Pyspark:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("OverlapCalculator").getOrCreate()
data = [
(123, "aaa", "2022-08-19", 30),
(123, "aaa", "2022-09-23", 30),
(123, "aaa", "2022-10-20", 30),
(123, "bbb", "2022-08-23", 90),
(123, "bbb", "2022-11-20", 90),
(234, "ttt", "2022-01-19", 90),
(234, "ttt", "2022-04-11", 90),
(234, "ttt", "2022-07-21", 90),
(234, "ttt", "2022-09-27", 90),
(234, "ttt", "2022-12-27", 90),
]
columns = ["ID", "Drug", "Start_dt", "day_supply"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df = df.withColumn("Start_dt", F.to_date("Start_dt"))
df = df.withColumn("day_supply", F.col("day_supply").cast("int"))
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID", "Drug").orderBy("Start_dt")
df = df.withColumn("End_dt", F.date_add("Start_dt", F.col("day_supply")))
df = df.withColumn("dt_diff", F.datediff(F.col("Start_dt"), F.lag("End_dt").over(window_spec)))
df = df.withColumn("Nw_Start", F.when(F.col("dt_diff") <= 0, F.date_add(F.lag("End_dt").over(window_spec), 1)).otherwise(F.col("Start_dt")))
df = df.withColumn("Nw_End_temp", F.when(F.col("dt_diff") <= 0, F.date_add(F.lag("End_dt").over(window_spec), F.col("day_supply"))).otherwise(F.col("End_dt")))
df = df.withColumn("Nw_End", F.when(F.col("Nw_End_temp").isNull(), F.date_add(F.col("Nw_Start"), F.col("day_supply"))).otherwise(F.col("Nw_End_temp")))
df = df.drop("Nw_End_temp")
df.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Dileepraj, Your PySpark code and the databricks SQL I had mentioned above is works well except one set of condition. The above codes is not aligned with ID 234's corresponding column from 4th row. Can you please help me to resolve this method for the ID's 234,  so that I can mark your answer as fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @Sathish Sure let me try that